# Can’t access Grub to reset root password

Tags: boot, grub2, 20.04, root, password-recovery

I can’t seem to access Grub on my HP Stream laptop (model 14-ds0033nr). Laptop came with windows 10, and I’m currently using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS as the sole OS.

My main issue is that I forgot my root password, and need access to Grub (I think..?) to change the password.

I’ve tried F1-F12, ESC, Shift, E,C following Post and nothing seems to work. I appreciate any help you guys can offer

Comment: One little trick I kind of learned is to reset the host right in the middle of it booting up.  It might detect that the previous boot is incomplete and bring up the grub menu.  Hold in the power button right after you see Ubuntu start to boot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

Answer (score 1):

Download 20.04 and write the ISO to USB. Boot to the USB. (You can usually select which to boot first by pressing F12, ESC, or sometimes F2 - it will vary depending on the computer you own as it's not a standardized key.)

Now, in the live environment, you're going to mount the disk.

```
mkdir /mnt/fix
mount /dev/sdXX /mnt/fix
```

`sdXX` is your hard drive - it's usually `sda`.

Next, you're going to `chroot` to temporarily mount it as root.

```
chroot /mnt/fix
```

The hard work is over. You just use `passwd` or `passwd <user>` follow it with `exit` (to get out of chroot) when you're done. Then, just unmount your disk with:

```
umount /mnt/fix
```

Reboot following the usual methods, being sure to remove the USB when prompted to do so. Your new password should be whatever you set it to.

Answer (score 0):

Menu will appear if you press and hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> during loading Grub, if you boot using BIOS. When your system boots using UEFI, press <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Comment: Ive done both though. Before and after it posts, holding, tapping, nothing will let me get to grub.